# Как получить самое большое и маленькое число объекта?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var object = { 
    "N102 - Number 102": {name: "1N02 - Number 102"},
    "N104 - Number 104": {name: "N104 - Number 104"},
    "N100 - Number 100": {name: "N100 - Number 100"},
    "N155 - Number 155": {name: "N155 - Number 155"},
    "N126 - Number 126": {name: "N126 - Number 126"},
    "N152 - Number 152": {name: "N152 - Number 152"},
    "N110 - Number 110": {name: "N110 - Number 110"},
    "N156 - Number 156": {name: "N156 - Number 156"}
};
```

Помогите получить самое большое и самое маленькое число, в данном случаи это должно быть 100 и 156.

Comment: Что пробовали и что не получилось?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let o = { 
    "N102 - Number 102": {name: "1N02 - Number 102"},
    "N104 - Number 104": {name: "N104 - Number 104"},
    "N100 - Number 100": {name: "N100 - Number 100"},
    "N155 - Number 155": {name: "N155 - Number 155"},
    "N126 - Number 126": {name: "N126 - Number 126"},
    "N152 - Number 152": {name: "N152 - Number 152"},
    "N110 - Number 110": {name: "N110 - Number 110"},
    "N156 - Number 156": {name: "N156 - Number 156"}
}

const a = Object.keys (o).map (k => k.split (' ').pop ()).sort ()

console.log (a.shift (), a.pop ())
```

Comment: Отлично брат, а что делать, если в списке есть, скажем "A8 - A 8": {name: "A8 - A 8"}, и вот это значение не долно выводиться, как минимальное. Как это сделать?

Comment: Отфильтровать то, что нужно. Как вариант: Object.keys (o).filter (k => k [0] == 'N').map (...).sort ()

Answer (score 0):

```
var min, max;
for (key in object) {
    var value = parseInt(key.match(/\d+/)[0]);
    !min ? min = value : value < min ? min = value : true;
    !max ? max = value : value > max ? max = value : true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var object = { 
  "N102 - Number 102": {name: "1N02 - Number 102"},
  "N104 - Number 104": {name: "N104 - Number 104"},
  "N100 - Number 100": {name: "N100 - Number 100"},
  "N155 - Number 155": {name: "N155 - Number 155"},
  "N126 - Number 126": {name: "N126 - Number 126"},
  "N152 - Number 152": {name: "N152 - Number 152"},
  "N110 - Number 110": {name: "N110 - Number 110"},
  "N156 - Number 156": {name: "N156 - Number 156"}
};

var a = Object.keys(object).map(x => +x.match(/\d+/));
console.log(Math.min(...a));
console.log(Math.max(...a));
```

Comment: Отлично брат, а что делать, если в списке есть, скажем "A8 - A 8": {name: "A8 - A 8"}, и вот это значение не долно выводиться, как минимальное. Как это сделать?